# GitLab Runner with scaled Runners and caching Docker images

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have created a docker registry mirror as follows:

`docker run -d -p 5000:5000 -e REGISTRY_PROXY_REMOTEURL=https://registry.gitlab.com --restart always --name registry registry:2`

I can `curl` to the registry:

```
$ curl REGISTRY_ADDRESS:5000/v2/
{}
```

When I try to download the image:

`docker run REGISTRY_ADDRESS:5000/group/project:tag`

I am getting:

```
Unable to find image 'REGISTRY_ADDRESS:5000/group/project:tag' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: manifest for 
REGISTRY_ADDRESS:5000/group/project:tag not found.
```

In `docker logs` I can see following:

```
time="2018-02-19T15:08:19Z" level=info msg="listening on [::]:5000" go.version=go1.7.6 instance.id=_____ version=v2.6.2
time="2018-02-19T15:08:58Z" level=info msg="response completed" go.version=go1.7.6 http.request.host="______:5000" http.request.id=28323951-f6f5-4386-b608-9e806507527a http.request.method=GET http.request.remoteaddr="______:35098" http.request.uri="/v2/" http.request.useragent="docker/17.12.0-ce go/go1.9.2 git-commit/c97c6d6 kernel/4.4.0-112-tag os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/17.12.0-ce \\(linux\\))" http.response.contenttype="application/json; charset=utf-8" http.response.duration=3.027696ms http.response.status=200 http.response.written=2 instance.id=_______ version=v2.6.2
10.135.29.97 - - [19/Feb/2018:15:08:58 +0000] "GET /v2/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2 "" "docker/17.12.0-ce go/go1.9.2 git-commit/c97c6d6 kernel/4.4.0-112-tag os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/17.12.0-ce \\(linux\\))"
time="2018-02-19T15:08:59Z" level=info msg="Challenge established with upstream : {https  <nil> registry.gitlab.com /v2/  %!s(bool=false)  } &{{{%!s(int32=0) %!s(uint32=0)} %!s(uint32=0) %!s(uint32=0) %!s(int32=0) %!s(int32=0)} map[https://registry.gitlab.com:443/v2/:[{bearer map[realm:https://gitlab.com/jwt/auth service:container_registry]}]]}" go.version=go1.7.6 http.request.host="_____:5000" http.request.id=c4db88c1-c2d4-4bd2-9731-904fe05f99ca http.request.method=GET http.request.remoteaddr="______:35100" http.request.uri="/v2/group/project/manifests/tag" http.request.useragent="docker/17.12.0-ce go/go1.9.2 git-commit/c97c6d6 kernel/4.4.0-112-tag os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/17.12.0-ce \\(linux\\))" instance.id=______ vars.name="group/project" vars.reference=tag version=v2.6.2
time="2018-02-19T15:08:59Z" level=error msg="response completed with error" err.code="manifest unknown" err.detail="unknown tag=tag" err.message="manifest unknown" go.version=go1.7.6 http.request.host="_____:5000" http.request.id=_____ http.request.method=GET http.request.remoteaddr="_____:35100" http.request.uri="/v2/group/project/manifests/tag" http.request.useragent="docker/17.12.0-ce go/go1.9.2 git-commit/c97c6d6 kernel/4.4.0-112-tag os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/17.12.0-ce \\(linux\\))" http.response.contenttype="application/json; charset=utf-8" http.response.duration=815.410843ms http.response.status=404 http.response.written=97 instance.id=_______ vars.name="group/project" vars.reference=tag version=v2.6.2
10.135.29.97 - - [19/Feb/2018:15:08:58 +0000] "GET /v2/group/project/manifests/tag HTTP/1.1" 404 97 "" "docker/17.12.0-ce go/go1.9.2 git-commit/c97c6d6 kernel/4.4.0-112-tag os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/17.12.0-ce \\(linux\\))"
```

From the error I am unable to say whether the registry mirror managed to connect to gitlab, which refused the connection or whether it didn't even try. I have googled through all the manuals for creating private registries, but noone seems to have the same issue.

**EDIT**

I find strange especially this part:

1. `Challenge established with upstream : {https  <nil> registry.gitlab.com}`
2. `http.request.remoteaddr="10.135.29.97:33144"`

But I guess the `remoteaddr` should be gitlab's address, but this is my private local address.

Comment: Shows a `404` did you push the image with the correct tag set?

Comment: It is definitely there, if i try `curl -v https://registry.gitlab.com/v2/group/project/manifests/tag` I am getting 401, not 404.

Comment: Also if I run it directyl `docker run registry.gitlab.com/group/project:tag` it works well as well.